# HERE API won't load map - H.Map (Argument #0 null)

Tags: javascript, here-api

I'm following the [HERE Maps API Quick Start Guide](https://developer.here.com/documentation/maps/topics/quick-start.html) to implement a map on my site. When using the exact code from this guide, I'm getting the following error in my browser (Chrome):

```
message: "H.Map (Argument #0 null)"stack: "Error↵    at new C (https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.1/mapsjs-core.js:35:1007)↵    at new Q (https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.1/mapsjs-core.js:340:639)↵
```

**HTML** (key parts only)

```
<head>    
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <script src="https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.1/mapsjs-core.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.1/mapsjs-service.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="mapContainer"></div>
</body>
```

**JavaScript**

```
var platform = new H.service.Platform({
  'apikey': 'uHrZJBCC_k98EXtICkx_7GH_QyFRSkAC1xoh7Rd02Pk'
});

var defaultLayers = platform.createDefaultLayers();

var map = new H.Map(
  document.getElementById('mapContainer'),
  defaultLayers.vector.normal.map,
  {
    zoom: 10,
    center: { lat: 52.5, lng: 13.4 }
  });
```

Comment: Is your JavaScript is loaded in the `<head>`? If so, `#mapContainer` [doesn't exist yet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14028959/why-does-jquery-or-a-dom-method-such-as-getelementbyid-not-find-the-element).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using a third-party library that loads some external resources make sure the protocol stays the same to avoid mixed content error and double-check your [Content-Security-Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CSP).

By taking your example in the issue description I was able to prepare a full-functional [demo on JsBin](https://jsbin.com/woyememuvi/edit?html,css,js,output).

```js
function loadMap() {
  var platform = new H.service.Platform({
  'apikey': 'uHrZJBCC_k98EXtICkx_7GH_QyFRSkAC1xoh7Rd02Pk'
  });

  var defaultLayers = platform.createDefaultLayers();

  var map = new H.Map(
    document.getElementById('mapContainer'),
    defaultLayers.vector.normal.map,
    {
      zoom: 10,
      center: { lat: 52.5, lng: 13.4 }
    });
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  console.log('DOM is ready');
  loadMap();
});
```

```css
#mapContainer {
  width: 640px;
  height: 350px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<script src="https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.1/mapsjs-core.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
  <script src="https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.1/mapsjs-service.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
  <div id="mapContainer"></div>
</body>
</html>
```